# Regex - extracting multiple elements in one line

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract multiple elements from string in RSS.
Because content field contains CDATA the element I am intrested in looks like:

`<li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li>`

Problem is, string appears in one line so 
`<li>(.+?)<\/li>` matches all the 3 elements in one group. And I need to extract each item between html tags and to make things worse the number of elements varies in every artcle from 1 to 5. Is there any way to dynamically create as many groups as necessary?

Comment: Please show the relevant code you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex `g` modifier to get all matches in an array. But really, to parse HTML you should not use regular expressions. Use the DOM capabilities offered in a browser context:

```js
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = "<li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li>";
var texts = Array.from(span.querySelectorAll('li'), li => li.textContent);

console.log(texts);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try this today. I was used to Regexes in Workflow but in that app you are operating on already decoded text.

Comment: Your idea works in JSFiddle, hower I am in IFTTT maker so I need to find another solution.

Comment: You mean you are running on node.js?

Comment: Not sure. IFTTT added new tool for making applets and inside you have ability to write code in TypeScript to manipulate input and output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regexes to obtain your code in blocks or not in blocks, but it seems you are doing some "elaborate parsing" of your HTML.

In these cases maybe an HTML parsing would work better than manipulate strings with regexes. 
By the way you can look at the following example in order to achieve your elements in block or as single elements, using regex:

```js
var pattern = /<ul><li>(.*?)<\/li><\/ul>/g;
var string = "<ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ul><ul><li>item 4</li><li>item 5</li></ul>";
var blockContent;
string.match(pattern).forEach(function(el) {
 blockContent = el.replace(/<ul>|<li>|<\/ul>|<\/li>/gi, '');
  console.log(blockContent);
});
var content;
string.match(pattern).forEach(function(el) {
 content = el.replace(/<ul>|<li>|<\/ul>/gi, '');
  content = content.split('</li>');
  content.length = content.length - 1;
  console.log(content);
});
```